# How do I get <div> to show & scroll with JQuery click to horizontally scroll coding?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to create a page that slides div's in and out via navigation arrows. A non-working demo can be seen here: drawmeahouse.com (the div on the right would slide to the middle, and the middle would slide to the mirror of where the right one is, and so on with more divs when they get added eventually...)

This is how far I've gotten, and failed so far,
drawmeahouse.com/index2.html

As you can see, the content is not showing in the middle and the navigation arrows are not moving anything at all! I'm pretty new to JQuery, so I'm trying to hack through this, but I need some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $('#nextControl').click(function() {
      $('#mask').animate({
        marginLeft: "-=200px"
      }, "fast");
   });
    $('#prevControl').click(function() {
      $('#mask').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "fast");
   });
});
```

Code need's to be executed `on render ready` or `on document ready`, which is done here after correcting some other syntax mistakes.
If you would like the see the content, remove the `visibility: hidden;` from the container's CSS.

Comment: I did this, but I'm still seeing the second container sitting under the first, and the controls aren't working. see (drawmeahouse.com/index2.html)

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">` - it is not good to treat a JS file as Stylesheet :)) Use `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` instead of that wrong reference. The problem is in `rel="stylesheet"` but is better to use newer version of `jQuery` too.

Comment: That fixed it! I just have to do some positioning now.

Thank you so much! I had no idea that js should just be src and not a stylesheet.

Comment: yep :) be careful with your code ... too much erros that kind of code :) pay more attention for details and check JS erros reported - suggesting use FireBug - best tools fora a developer. Good luck.

Comment: Side-note: Is there a way to put a stopper on it so that when it's on the fist div, you can't scroll further left and when it's on the last div, you can't scroll further right?

Answer (score 1):

need to animate the divs on click... something like:

```
$('.next').click(
     function(){
          $('.shadow').animate({ left: '-=600px' })
     }
)
```

that will move all divs with the class `shadow` to the left effectively bring the div to the right into the main view. id use a different class like `content` or something because im sure you will reuse the `shadow` class on other elements.

divs will have to be absolute to animate the left property.

or you can put them all into one container with the container positioned absolutely and move the entire container as opposed to just the divs

Comment: I did this and reuploaded (drawmeahouse.com/index2.html) and it's still not showing anything.

Comment: try something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jxGJ/4/).. but of course adjust any numbers to fit your scenario..